# C# fails to delete database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

when I'm trying to delete a database using c#, method

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.KillDatabase(String
>   database).

it fails. Error message is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User does not have permission to
>   alter database 'My_Database_Name', the database does not exist, or the
>   database is not in a state that allows access checks. ALTER DATABASE
>   statement failed.".

Things I know :

1) Database exists;
2) Login name and password are correct;
3) Before it worked good, but after i added 3 additional tables to the database, it stopped working.

What could be the reason, why it fails to delete a database ?

My code is :

```
if (server.Databases.Contains(databaseName))
{
    server.KillDatabase(databaseName);
}
```

Comment: Also make sure your connection string is pointing to `master` database instead of the `My_Database_Name`. I think the biggest suspect is your permissions on this server.

Comment: `or the database is not in a state that allows access checks. ALTER DATABASE statement failed.".` this line here makes me think you are connecting to the databases itself to drop it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
sqlCommandText = "DROP DATABASE [databaseName]";
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText , connection);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Assuming that the user has the permission to drop  the database.

Also  you could try to set

```
USE master; 
ALTER DATABASE databaseName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
DROP DATABASE databaseName;
```